# validation of EditText by TextWatcher or AwesomeValidation Library

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have created a Registration form with Name,age,gender and salary.Now i am trying to do validation for all the fields.
I came up with lot of examples n links on validation using Text Watcher and various validation libraries like Awesome Validation,Android-Validator Library etc.
I am bit confused here,I need to know which one to use ? and why? 
A little bit of explanation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create validation  as per your requirement i think its not good idea to use  `validation libraries`

**you can apply validation to your form controls like this**

```
 EditText editText = .findViewById(R.id.btn_FBShare);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_FBShare);
    //set validation on button click like this
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                editText.setError("enetr user name");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enetr user name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Valid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

           if(editText.getText().toString().length()<10){
                editText.setError("less than 10 charecter");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please entermore than 10 charecter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

**let me now if you have any doubt**

Comment: do i need to use addTextChangeListener() method to check other constrains like maxlength,minlength or just use if..else statement

Comment: after using addTextChangeListener()method i am getting application not responding dialog box and emulator slows down

Comment: @Smitha_nj check my updated ans and ask me in case of any query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String Name = editTextField.getText().toString().trim();  
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {
            lName.setError("Please enter name");
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to use validation Library? Form validation is always depends on the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextWatcher for real time validation if you want:

```
editTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            validate(s.toString());
        }
    });
```

If you want to validate the form after clicking a button or similar use Nileshs answer!

Comment: while doing real time validation ,how to avoid the error message that will come immediately when we run the application .

Comment: please enter name will come immediately after running app before entering name since the Name field is empty.

Comment: Depends on where you put the call.